# Get N sample even if sub values has less data from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

I have a data frame, that has three columns m_name, description, type. The type has values "c" and "b". I want to get 50 samples each for each name in the data frame, 25 each for type c and b. I was able to do this by the following code.

```
sam_size=50 
mlist=list(df['m_name'].unique())
s=int(sam_size/2)
df_s=pd.DataFrame()
for m in mlist:
    x=df[df['m_name']==m]
    #print(m+":"+str(len(x)))
    #a=0
    lb=len(x[x['type']=='b'])
    lc=len(x[x['type']=='c'])
    
    print(m+":"+str(len(x))+":"+str(lb)+":"+str(lc))
    
    if(len(x[x['type']=='b'])<s):
        df_s=df_s.append(x[x['type']=='b'])
    else:
        df_s=df_s.append(x[x['type']=='b'].sample(n=s))
        
    if(len(x[x['type']=='c'])<s):
        df_s=df_s.append(x[x['type']=='c'])
    else:
        df_s=df_s.append(x[x['type']=='c'].sample(n=s))
```

In the above code, if any particular type has less than 25 values, the code will take the entire values as the sample.

The issue I face is if 'b' has 100 values and 'c' has only 10 values the sample will have only 25 'b' and 10 'c'.

What I would like to have in the above condition fill up the rest from the type 'b'.

So the idea is if any m_name has more than 50 numbers I want to get 50 samples even if one of the types has less than 25.

Is there any way I can get this easily with sample functions advance methods?

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop and append. try `groupby().sample`:

```
df.groupby(['m_name','type']).sample(n=25, replace=True)
```

If you want to sample without replacement when possible (e.g. more than `25` available):

```
(df.groupby(['m_name','type'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=25, replace= len(x) < 25)
)
```